# windowWillResize moves the origin of the window

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

I'm currently using windowWillResize to control the aspect ratio of one of my windows with relation to one of its views. Everything seems to work fine, except that resizing the window also moves it vertically, just slightly, each time it's resized. Using setContentAspectRatio doesn't produce this, but that's not an option for me, because I have other views in the window.

Any ideas on why the window may be moving, and more importantly, if it's preventable? Here's the code:

```
- (NSSize)windowWillResize:(NSWindow *)sender toSize:(NSSize)frameSize
{
    NSRect windowFrame = [self.window frame];
    NSRect viewRect = [self.screen convertRect:[self.screen bounds] toView: nil];
    NSRect contentRect = [self.window contentRectForFrameRect:windowFrame];

    float marginY = viewRect.origin.y + windowFrame.size.height - contentRect.size.height;
    float marginX = contentRect.size.width - viewRect.size.width;

    frameSize.height = (frameSize.width - marginX) * HEIGHT_DEFAULT / WIDTH_DEFAULT + marginY;

    return frameSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by changing the width of 'frameSize', instead of height:

```
frameSize.width = (frameSize.height - marginY) / (HEIGHT_DEFAULT / WIDTH_DEFAULT) + marginX;
```

This produces a strange window resizing artifact if the window is shrunk to a negative size, but setting a minimum size limitation fixes that.